# How to get the ratio from a function of N?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

The exercise gave us a chart which showed the running time as a $N$ increases:

\begin{array}{c|c}
N & \text{seconds}\\\hline
      256   &  0.000\\
      512   &  0.000\\
     1024   &  0.002\\
     2048   &  0.009\\
     4096   &  0.042\\
     8192   &  0.175\\
    16384   &  0.788\\
    32768   &  3.440\\
    65536   & 15.010\\
   131072   & 65.873\\
   262144   & 290.449\\
   524288   & 1272.816\\
\end{array}

My process was to use the power law to figure out the growth of the running time.

$$T(n)=aN^b$$

I divided the seconds and figured out that as $N$ doubles the running time quadruples, indicating a quadratic growth rate or $b=2$. So then I simply put in $1272.816$ as $T(n)$ and $2$ for $b$ and solved for $a$:

\begin{align*}
T(n)&=aN^b\\
1272.816 &= a 524288^2\\
a &= \frac{1272.816}{524288^2}\\
a &= 4.630 \cdot 10^{-9}
\end{align*}

It turns out my answer was wrong when I looked at the answer. The actual answer computed the ratio and the used the $\log_2$ of that ratio to determine where the running time converges:

> The theoretical order-of-growth is $N^\left(\frac{32}{15}\right) = 2.13$
>
> The empirical order-of-growth is $N^{\log_2 \text{ratio}}$
>
> \begin{array}{c|c} N & \text{seconds} & \text{ratio} & \log_2\text{ratio}\\\hline
>       256  &   0.000    &     -    &     -\\
>       512  &   0.000    &     -    &     -\\
>      1024  &   0.002    &     -    &     -\\
>      2048  &   0.009    &  4.50    &  2.17\\
>      4096  &   0.042    &  4.67    &  2.22\\
>      8192  &   0.175    &  4.17    &  2.06\\
>     16384  &   0.788    &  4.50    &  2.17\\
>     32768  &   3.440    &  4.37    &  2.13\\
>     65536  &   15.010    &  4.36    &  2.13\\    131072  &   65.873    &  4.39    &  2.13\\    262144  &   290.449   &   4.41   &   2.14\\    524288  &   1272.816  &    4.38  &    2.13\\ \end{array}

I'm not sure how they got the ratio. In the video the instructor said to double the input $N$ and compute the ratio of the running time of $N$ and $2N$. Looking at the $\log_2$ tells us what $b$ is.

Here are my questions:

- How did they determine the theoretical and empirical growth order?
- Can you give a step by step instruction on how to get the ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratios are simply computed as the name suggest (provided the time values are non-zero):

```
      0.009/0.002 = 4.5000    log2(0.009/0.002) =  2.1699
      0.042/0.009 = 4.6667    log2(0.042/0.009) =  2.2224
      0.175/0.042 = 4.1667    log2(0.175/0.042) =  2.0588
                  ...                          ...
   290.449/65.873 = 4.4092    log2(...)         =  2.1405
 1272.816/290.449 = 4.3822    log2(...)         =  2.1316
```

I give four decimal digits, in your source the values are rounded to two digits.
The empirical growth rate is just the *limit* (or the *best fit*, or *mean* of the last, or ...)  of the log2(ratio) values. $32/15\;$ is just a good approximation to 2.13, but IMO a *theoretical growth rate* is somewhat meaningless without a **theory** behind the process.

Comment: So where does the power law come into this? I saw it being used to solve a similar problem in the lectures.

Comment: @user6607: I don't know. As I have written, you gave no description of **what** is timed. There are many algorithms which have a complexity of $O(N^2)\;$ e.g. some sorting algorithms, school-book multiplication of large integers etc.

Comment: Yeah the exercise doesn't tell us much about what is being timed either: `Suppose that you time a program as a function of N and produce
the following table. Estimate the order of growth of the running time as a function of N.
Assume that the running time obeys a power law T(N) ~ a N^b.`

Comment: @user6607: Generally you can use power laws for processes where the logarithms of the variables show a linear dependency $\ln y = a \ln x,\;$ or when the relative changes are proportional
$$\frac{\Delta y}{y} = a \frac{\Delta x}{x}\approx\frac{dy}{y} = a \frac{dx}{x} \Longrightarrow y(x) = b x^a$$